# Getting access of inner class Spring/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, inner-classes

What I'm trying to do is call a method which is inside an inner class, the problem begins when I try to call it from other class. Let's say I have the class DlgSendSAP which has an inner class called LongTask in which I have another inner class called ActualTask which has my method that I want to call. What is the problem here? 
I have read a lot of Hibernate and Spring and I know the basics but this drives me crazy and I don't know if is a problem of IoC. Any help will be appreciated.

Class DlgSendSAP

```
public class DlgSendSAP {
  ...
  dlgCargarTxt = ((DlgCargarTxt) SpringContext.getContext().getBean(DlgCargarTxt.class));
                    try {
                        dlgCargarTxt.ejecutarTask();
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
}
```

Class DlgCargarTxt

```
public class DlgCargarTxt {
  private LongTask.ActualTask actualTask;
  ...
     public void ejecutarTask() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
      actualTask = ((LongTask.ActualTask) SpringContext.getContext().getBean(LongTask.ActualTask.class));
      actualTask.executeTask();
    } 
  class LongTask {
  ...
    class ActualTask {
      ...
      public void executeTask() {
      ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got an error when the bean from my inner class ActualTask will be called.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [dunosusa.pos.view.LongTask] is defined: expected single bean but found 0: 
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:271)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083)
    at dunosusa.pos.view.DlgCargarTxt.ejecutarTask(DlgCargarTxt.java:135)
    at dunosusa.pos.view.admin.DlgSendSAP.escogerArchivos(DlgSendSAP.java:63)
    at dunosusa.pos.view.admin.DlgSendSAP.<init>(DlgSendSAP.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:958)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:911)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083)
    at dunosusa.pos.controller.AccionController$ActionPerformed.actionPerformed(AccionController.java:392)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:357)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1223)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1264)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6263)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6028)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4630)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4574)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4238)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4460)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:599)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: First thing, if you're needing to have a three tiered class - you need to rethink the Architecture of your project. That is not good very practice. Secondly, please give the xml of your bean configuration. I see that you're not using annotations for your bean configuration - why not?

Comment: The problem is I can't make new classes, at least no new ones to separate modules because it would affect many modules so it will be a problem to re-estructure the whole project which is huge. I'm sorry for being a newbie about Spring and Hibernate but I think that the class DlgCargarTxt has no XML configuration. I've been searching for it the last 20 minutes but have no clue.

Answer (score 0):

By using SpringContext.getContext().getBean() - you're searching through Spring's bean pool to get the class you're looking for. In order for the bean to be in Spring's bean pool, you have to define the inner classes as beans as well.

I see that you're using XML for your configuration. You should configure your inner classes like so:

```
<bean id="inner" class="innerbeans.Outer$Inner">
```

But, again, this is NOT very good practice. Why not just extract the classes and make them their own?

Comment: Thanks for the response, the problem about making separate clases is that I didn't make the original classes, I started working with the project when it was 90% done, actually I'm just solving issues so I can't make classes unless a new module need to be done.

Comment: Understood. As long as you understand the best practices ;) - Does my solution work for you though?

Comment: @Blackmore : There must be some configuration - Spring does not simply configure itself. There should be some form of annotations such as "@Controller", "@Service", "@Repository", sprint-context.xml, or even a Java-Config component.